# Passing a variable from JSP to Java

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to pass a string variable called `seq` from a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) to a Java program, and pass it on to the another Java program by passing the string as an argument to its object. I am somehow getting stuck.

**Start.jsp:**

```
<%@ page import="org.dypbbi.nirmiti.ProtModMain %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>NIRMITI</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please wait...</h1>
        <%
            String seq=request.getParameter("s");
            ProtModMain.getSequence(seq);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ProtModMain.java:**

```
package org.dypbbi.nirmiti;
public class ProtModMain {
    String sequence="";

    public static String getSequence(String str)
    {
        return str;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
      ProtModMain MainObj = new ProtModMain();
      sequence = MainObj.getSequence();
      new ObjectFactory(sequence);
    }
}
```

Start.jsp will retrieve the string value from the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). It passes the string to `ProtModMain` class via the method `getSequence`. I now need to use the string value to pass it to other classes that require it, so I intend to pass it a parameter to the `ObjectFactory` object. But before that, I need to call the `getSequence` method in the `ProtModMain` class so that I can pass the value. I am not understanding how to call the `getSequence` method in the main method of `ProtModMain` class.

Comment: You have a misconception of how `jsp`s work and how they **should** be used. Take a look at the wiki for both [`jsp`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [`servlets`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: How come a main method in a web application!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameter to the request using ***`request.setAttribute("<name>",<value>)`***. Then you can get it in the Java file using ***`request.getAttribute("<name>")`***.

Reference - Oracle Docs - [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

Comment: request has no "setParameter" method

Comment: Referring to the oracle docs [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) the right way is to use **_`getAttribute`_** and **_`setAttribute`_** methods. 

**_`request.setAttribute("<name>",<value>)`_**
and 

**_`request.getAttribute("<name>")`_**

Correcting Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<form>` tags and `<input type='hidden'>` with an `<input type='submit'>` button, in the form you will specify the method to send and to where send the data.

Or you can store in POJOs and store in session and recover it with a servlet.

Or use Ajax with an XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `main` method. In your JSP you are calling only the static `getSequence` that, by the way, only returns the value.

I think you have a project concept problem: why your web (JSP) app has a main class?

I think you should adapt:

Start.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="org.dypbbi.nirmiti.ProtModMain %> 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>NIRMITI</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please wait...</h1>
        <%
        String seq=request.getParameter("s");
        ProtModMain protModMain = new ProtModMain();
        ObjectFactory myFactory = protModMain.createFactory(seq);
        //do whatever you want with your factory ;)
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

ProtModMain.java:

```
package org.dypbbi.nirmiti;
public class ProtModMain {

    public ObjectFactory createFactory(final String sequence) {
        return new ObjectFactory(sequence);
    }
}
```

This way you will be calling the methods you intended to.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking, what if I avoid the ProtModMain.java class all together. I can pass the value directly to the ObjectFactory class and avoid the middle man, right?                                                 String seq=request.getParameter("s");                                   new ObjectFactory(seq);                                              the ObjectFactory class will directly receive the string value. This will work right?

Comment: @kuks Yes, will work and, if you are only instantiating `ProdModMain` to get a `ObjectFactory` instance, I think that it is much more clean to get to the `ObjectFactory` directly. You could avoid even the variable: `new ObjectFactory(request.getParameters("s"));`